# how to manipulate HTTP json response data in Java

Tags: java, json, http, httpresponse

```
HttpGet getRequest=new HttpGet("/rest/auth/1/session/");
getRequest.setHeaders(headers);
httpResponse = httpclient.execute(target,getRequest);

entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

Output as follows in json format

```
----------------------------------------
{"session":{"name":"JSESSIONID","value":"5F736EF0A08ACFD7020E482B89910589"},"loginInfo":{"loginCount":50,"previousLoginTime":"2014-11-29T14:54:10.424+0530"}}
----------------------------------------
```

What I want to know is how to you can manipulate this data using **Java** without writing it to a file?
I want to print name, value in my code

Jackson library is preferred but any would do.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you prefer Jackson, why don't you just create bean class and deserialize it to the bean with ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [this JSON](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) library to parse your json string into JSONObject and read value from that object as show below :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
JSONObject sessionObj =  json.getJSONObject("session");
System.out.println(sessionObj.getString("name"));
```

You need to read upto that object from where you want to read value. Here you want the value of `name` parameter which is inside that `session` object, so you first get the value of `session` as JSONObject using [getJSONObject(KeyString)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) and read `name` value from that object using function [getString(KeyString)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) as show above.

May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two ways to do it without a library.

NEW (better) Answer:

`findInLine` might work even better. (`scannerName.findInLine(pattern);`)

Maybe something like:

```
s.findInLine("{"session":{"name":"(\\w+)","value":"(\\w+)"},"loginInfo":{"loginCount":(\\d+),"previousLoginTime":"(\\w+)"}}");
```

w matches word characters (letters, digits, and underscore), d matches digits, and the + makes it match more than once (so it doesnt stop after just one character).

Read about patterns here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

OLD Answer:

I'm pretty sure you could use a scanner with a custom delimiter here.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\"");
```

Should return something like:

```
{
session
:{
name
:
JSESSIONID
,
value
:
5F736EF0A08ACFD7020E482B89910589
```

And so on. Then just sort through that list/use a smarter delimiter/remove the unnecessary bits.
Getting rid of every other item is a pretty decent start.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html has info on this.

Answer (score 2):

I higly recomend [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

```
private static final HttpRequest<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> HTTP_REQUEST = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(yourUri, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>{})
    .addDefaultHeaders(headers)
    .build();

public void send(){
   ResponseHandler<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> responseHandler = HTTP_REQUEST.execute();
   Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = responseHandler.get();
}
```

If you want use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) you can:

```
entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = mapper.readValue(entity.getContent(),  new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>{});
```