# conversion of xml data into string

Tags: java, xml, json, jsp, servlets

I am getting the output in xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
<first-name>xxxxxxxxx</first-name>
<last-name>xxxxxxxx</last-name>
<email-address>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</email-address>
</person>
```

i want to read the values in String form to use it for further . my code is below:

```
     String accesstok=AccessToken.toString();
     OAuthRequest request2 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)?oauth2_access_token="+accesstok);
     Response response2 = request2.send();
```

Comment: You should parse the XML. Read here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK19083

Comment: Try to use toString() method. Or you want to get data(first-name, last-name, etc.) from XML?

Comment: i want to get (first-name,last-name, etc) from XML

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to [how to manipulate HTTP json response data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201201/how-to-manipulate-http-json-response-data-in-java), maybe some of the answers there could help you? I'd suggest, as I did there, looking into Scanner delimiters, Scanner.findInLine, or Scanner.findWithinHorizon.

For example:

```
s.findWithinHorizon("<first-name>(\\w+)</first-name>");
MatchResult firstNameResult = s.match();
s.findWithinHorizon("<last-name>(\\w+)</last-name>");
MatchResult lastNameResult = s.match();
s.findWithinHorizon("<email-address>(\\w+)</email-address>");
MatchResult emailResult = s.match();
```